# Jesus told his twelve they would not all taste death before they saw the Kingdom of God and Son of Man come with clouds of heaven. How could that be?

Tags: prophecy, eschatology, apocalyptic

Jesus says this to his disciples in Mark 9:1 and in Mark 14 he tells the Jeruslem Temple authorities who were about to condemn him to death that they ("you," pl.) will see the Son of Man coming with the clouds of heaven. Wouldn't that indicate that he was convinced that at least some of them would still be alive to see that happen?